# VCenter Upgrade Does not work

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

**Task/Details**

We need to upgrade our Vcenter enviornment from `v4.1.0 Build Number: 799345` to `v4.1.0 Update 3 Build Number: 816786`

**Problem**

After backing up the database and the SSL certificates we run the update from the .zip file provided by VMWare located [here](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=230&downloadGroup=VC41U3).  It alerts us that we will be updating and if we wish to continue the update finishes without any errors and all clients are pushed new agents correctly as well.  However, when we check the version information it still shows `Build Number: 799345` as though the update was never run.  As far as I can tell it should be `Build Number: 816786`.

Any ideas why VCenter is not actually updating properly?  There are no errors.

Comment: How are you actually running the update? We're missing that detail.

Comment: vCenter is a management component/server. Are you updating your vCenter server or are you updating your vSphere hosts or both? What exactly have you updated?

Comment: @ewwhite I updated via the .zip file from VMWare and clicked `autorun.exe`. I then selected VCenter Server which then prompted me that it would now move through the upgrade process. Link I used is attached. Its a closed system so the upgrade was burned to a disc first.

Comment: @joeqwerty  I am updating vCenter Server not both.  I have updated VCenter Server and it successfully pushed out new agents, I saw all them get updates through the console but it still shows old version info when I run `"C:\Program Files\VMware\Infrastructure\VirtualCenter Server\vpxd.exe" -v`